# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n) +\cos(n)}{n^2}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My apologies if this question is a duplicate. My attempt to show that it is convergent:

$\left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n) + \cos(n)}{n^2} \right|= \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n)}{n^2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n^2} \right|$

$ \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n)}{n^2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n^2} \right| \leq \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n)}{n^2} \right| + \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n^2} \right| \leq  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\sin(n)}{n^2} \right| + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{\cos(n)}{n^2} \right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^2} = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent then by the Comparison Test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n) + \cos(n)}{n^2}$ is absolutely convergent. Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n) + \cos(n)}{n^2}$ is convergent.

I would like to know if the above is correct.

Comment: I think your logic is correct, but could probably be written a bit more succinctly

Comment: $\sin(n)+\cos(n) = \sqrt{2}\sin(n+\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: @haman_Abdallah: Thank you for this very useful comment; however, perhaps you meant $\sin(n+\frac{\pi}{4})$ instead of $\sin(n+\frac{\pi}{2})$ since $\sin(n+\frac{\pi}{4}) = \sin(n)/\sqrt 2 +\cos(n)/\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The idea is fine, but there are a few problems:

- You write that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)+\cos(n)}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}$, but this equality assumes that the three series involved are convergent. However, you are supposed to prove that the first one converges.
- You write that $\displaystyle\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)+\cos(n)}{n^2}\right|\leqslant\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n^2}\right|+\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}\right|$, but, again, this assumes that you are dealing with *numbers*, that is, once again you are assuming that all those series are convergent.

You can simple say that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\left|\frac{\sin(n)+\cos(n)}{n^2}\right|\leqslant\frac2{n^2}$$and then apply the comparison test. Note that this means to compare the *terms* of the given series with the *terms* of a convergent series.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see my mistakes. Perhaps to arrive at the last inequality we should write that $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})$: $\left| \frac{\sin(n) + \cos(n)}{n^2} \right| \leq \left| \frac{\sin(n)}{n^2} \right|+ \left| \frac{\cos(n)}{n^2} \right|$ to show where the ``2'' in $\frac{2}{n^2}$ comes from.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Regarding your first bullet point: technically speaking, it's not necessary to assume that all three series converge. This equality only assume that any two of the three converge, and then it follows that the third one converges and the equality holds. For practical purposes, it's most natural to apply the assumption to the two series on the left-hand side: if those two converge, then so does their "sum" and it's equal to the sum of the two.

Comment: I think that you should emphasise that you have applied the Comparison Test correctly, applying the comparison to the *terms* of the series and not to the sums of the series as the OP attempts to do.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Done.